# express.js infinite loading url and get request not handling any of the code

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, discord, discord.js

so, i am trying to make a discord oauth2 bot. but when i click authorize on the discord authorize url, it just infinite loads with callback?code=authcode.

this is the discord authorize url: [discord authorize url](https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=1151975757229326526&redirect_uri=https://verification-tejh.onrender.com/auth/discord/callback&response_type=code&scope=identify%20guilds.join)

anyone know how to fix this?

this is my code for handling the request.

```
/* Core API */
const client = require('./Utils/client');
const auth = require('./Core/AuthClient')
const venusClient = new auth(client);
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const fs = require('fs');

.....


/* Core Auth Modules */
const DiscordOauth2 = require("discord-oauth2");
const oauth = new DiscordOauth2();

/* Core Auth Web Configuration */
app.set('trust proxy', 1);
app.listen(config.web.port, () => { log(`Auth Scanner is running on port ${config.web.port}`) });

....
app.get('/auth/discord/callback', async (req, res) => {
    try {
    const code = req.query.code;
    const token = await oauth.tokenRequest({
      clientId: config.client.id,
      clientSecret: config.client.secret,
      code: code,
      scope: config.client.scope,
      grantType: 'authorization_code',
      redirectURI: config.client.redirect_uri,
    });
    } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error.message);
    res.send('Error occurred during login.');
    }

    let user = oauth.getUser(token);

    let user_ = await venusClient.fetchUser(user.id);
    let botData = await botSchema.findOne({ clientId: client.user.id });

    let ip = req.clientIp || null;
    if (ip) {
        ip = ip.split(':')[3];
    }

    let aronshire_ = await axios.get(`https://api.ipregistry.co/${ip}?key=${config.web.apiKey}`).then(res => res.data).catch();
    let countryCode = aronshire_?.location?.country?.code || null

    let userData = {
        id: user.id,
        username: user.username,
        discriminator: user.discriminator,
        avatar: `https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/${req.user.id}/${req.user.avatar}.png`,
        accessToken: user.accessToken,
        refreshToken: user.refreshToken,
        expiresDate: Date.now() + 604800,
        locale: `:flag_${countryCode.toLowerCase()}:`,
        ip: `${ip}`,
    }

    let badges;
    if (user_.flags.toArray().length > 0) {

......

    } else {
        badges = 'None';
    }
    
    venusClient.saveAuth(client.user.id, userData);
    venusClient.sendWebhook({
       
......

    if (botData.autoJoin[0]?.status === true) {

        venusClient.joinServer(userData.accessToken, botData.autoJoin[0].guildID, userData.id);
        venusClient.sendWebhook({
            embeds: [
                ...

   // res.redirect('https://discord.com/oauth2/authorized'); 
   // discord yetkilendirmesi
    res.redirect('/verified');
    
  });
```

i use mongodb server to store the auth codes, i dont think thats the problem tho because, the mongodb can connect.

anyone know how to fix this? it just litterly infinite loads. in dev tools the request also gives no response headers.

Comment: fixed it, my request to

Comment: i changed ```let user = oauth.getUser(token);``` to ```let user = oauth.getUser(token.data.access_token);```